# Is it possible to use a webhook connection for teams to edit/update message?

Tags: c#, azure, webhooks, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a strange question. I am currently using an incoming webhook in my function app to connect to the channel in Microsoft Teams. For now, I can only add messages or cards, but I want to be able to change or update the added messages or cards. I check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL), but can't find a solution. Then I found this article for [adaptive cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/overview-adaptive-cards). But I am not sure if it is the right thing to do. So my question is: is it possible to update added messages in teams via webhook, or should I use the graph client API instead?

Thank you .

I am trying to edit an added message in Teams via webhook, but I am not sure it is the right approach. So I am asking for better approaches.